# Make UITableView ignore Safe Area

Tags: swift, tableview, uiedgeinsets, safeareaview

I have a `TableView` inside a `ViewController`.
I made the `TableView` stretch to the View SuperMargings (with constraints) and disabled all `SafeArea` Inset options but my `TableView` is still under the `SafeArea` when I run my project.

How can I make my `TableView` go full height on iPhones with notch?

Comment: How did you set AutoLayout? Using Constraint in storyboard or via progarmatically ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you have already pinned `tableView` to it's superview(not to `safeArea`) with constraints but `tableView` still respects `safeArea` there is property `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` in `UIScrollView`(`UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView` as we know) since iOS 11.

This property is `UIScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` enum with 4 options.
You need to set `.never` to `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`.

Answer (score 3):

What works with *any* view is to associate the bottom constraint of the table view to the bottom anchor of the root (or parent) view (instead of the SafeArea).

This can be done in the storyboard editor double clicking on the constraint in the right inspector and changing the first item anchor from SafeArea to Superview (or any wanted view).

You can then set the edge insets at will if needed (to avoid content remain partially hidden behind the rounded frame corners or the notch if applying the same procedure to the top anchor)

[image]

Comment: Can you show the view hierarchy in the storyboard (the same applies when done programmatically tho)?